# Why MVC4 web app does not use logged in windows authentication credential to access MVC4 web api service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC4 web-app uses AppPoolIdentity to access MVC4 web-api service running on a different server, instead of using logged in user's Windows authentication credentials. Windows authentication is enabled on both sites.

Http client code to access web-api service;

```
using (HttpClientHandler _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
_clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler, true))
{
// code to get data
}
}
```

I am using ApiController.User to get logged in user's details at web-api controller.

How do I get logged in user's credentials passed over to web-api service?